# php singleton with static late binding

Tags: php, singleton

I am trying to understand how this Singleton implementation works.

```
final class UserFactory
{
    /**
     * Call this method to get singleton
     *
     * @return UserFactory
     */
    public static function Instance()
    {
        static $inst = null;
        if ($inst === null) {
            echo "inst was null \n";
            $inst = new UserFactory();
        }
        else {
            echo "inst was not null this time \n";
        }
        return $inst;
    }

    /**
     * Private ctor so nobody else can instance it
     *
     */
    private function __construct()
    {

    }
}

echo "get user1 \n";
$user1 = UserFactory::Instance();
echo "get user2 \n";
$user2 = UserFactory::Instance();

if ($user1 === $user2){
    echo "they are the same obj \n";
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
get user1 
inst was null 
get user2 
inst was not null this time 
they are the same obj
```

I dont understand why the first time $inst is initialised as null and the $inst === null test passes but the same does not happens on later calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `$inst` was declared as a *static* variable.. If you remove the *static* keyword , then you will get `null` the second time.

From the [PHP Docs..](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

> A static variable exists only in a local function scope, **but it does
>   not lose its value** when program execution leaves this scope.

Comment: I understand that but how comes that the variable does not get re-assigned with NULL on later invokes of UserFactory::Instance?

Comment: That is the thing behind _static_ and the reason I extracted that line from the PHP Docs to you.. The value will not be overwritten again by _null_

Comment: I understand that a class static variable will be kept in memory; what I did not understand (and perhaps I misunderstood) is that PHP will not redeclare a static variable if it already exists.

Comment: Not just a class static variable, It applies to normal static variables that are inside a function.. See this [**code**](https://eval.in/150132) and also check the 4th example on this link for more info http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Comment: thank you for the explicit explaination; perhaps you can add that in your answer too? I am pretty sure lots of people dont get that (and php docs are not really promoting that piece of information that much)